# JSON: Serialize Guava Optional

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, guava, option-type

Is there a Json Serializer/Deserializer for com.google.common.base.Optional?

Out of the box this doesn't seem to work with Jackson, see below:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import com.google.common.base.Optional;

public class TestClass {

public Optional<String> myString;

public TestClass() {
    myString = Optional.of("testString");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testClass);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
}
```

}

-> {"myString":{"present":true}}

Comment: Could you provide the exception stack trace?

Comment: there is no exception. The serialization that is output is {"myString":{"present":true}}
However, i'm missing the actual value of the String

Answer (score 12):

There is indeed a [Guava module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava) for Jackson on GitHub, but Optional is not supported (yet). Seems like a rather straightforward serializer/deserializer to implement; the behaviour should be fairly similar to @JsonUnwrapped, so for your simple test the result should be:

{"myString":"testString"}

and for an Optional.absent the serialized form should be:

{"myString":null}

**Update**: Seemed simple enough so I've just implemented it and pushed it to GitHub. You can get it via the official repo and build from source, or wait for the next official release. Enjoy!

Comment: as per note for the other question, this was included in version 2.1 of the Guava module.

Comment: `new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new GuavaModule()).readValue(..)` works for me now, as of 16 Nov 2016

Answer (score 3):

There is a library with Guava Jackson serializers/deserializers [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava). However there is no  one for `optional`. But it is a really basic class, and you can write one yourself easily following the samples there. Then you can pass the code to [Tatu](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/tatu-saloranta/0/36/b2b) so he can add it to the library and that would be appreciated.

Comment: Support for `Optional` is included in versions 2.1 and above (Nov-2013).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same the problem and i resolved my problem by using a JsonSerializer and a JsonDeserializer as the [How to serialize / deserialize a Option<> class (functional java) with JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955495/how-to-serialize-deserialize-a-option-class-functional-java-with-json/22956094?noredirect=1#comment35052206_22956094). Hope this helps.